# Integrating position/displacement with respect to time

Tags: kinematics, terminology, integration, displacement

We know that we get displacement if we integrate velocity with respect to time. But from my curiosity I am now wonder, what will I get if I integrate position/displacement with respect to time?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are talking about is [*absition* or *absement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absement).

Absement is actually the integral of position over time. So as you asked, integrating distance with respect to time mean adding up all the distances over time.

$$A= \int X \,{\rm d}t$$

In other words, the derivative of Absement is Distance

$$ \dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}A=X $$

and the second Derivative of Absement is Velocity

$$ \dfrac{\rm d^2}{{\rm d}t^2}A=v $$

Comment: how can the differentiation of $A$ be velocity $v$. As the unit for A is ms . So differentiating it will give us something with a unit m, which is not equal to velocity. So how can this be possible?

Comment: I am sorry for that. My bad. Its actually Distance. Rate of change of Absement is Distance. The second Derivative of Absement is Velocity.

Comment: Isn't it an abstract thing?

Comment: @AsifIqubal Not really. Have you read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absement) page? See the "Occurrence in nature" Section.